# Problem with responses of concurrent request axios

Tags: node.js, axios, concurrency

I'm trying to make two recurring requests with axios. I'm testing with a fake client and server to understand the concept of this, but I'm still getting errors dealing with both responses:

The server has an array that I want to send and two routes that add data in this array:

```
const users = {
  id: 1,
  name: "John Doe",
  username: "jd",
  pro: false,
  todos: [],
}

app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.body;

  users.id = id;
  console.log(users);

  return res.json(users);
});

app.post("/todos", (req, res) => {
  const {todos} = req.body;

  users.todos.push(todo)
  console.log(users)

  return res.json(users);
});
```

The client makes the requisitions to both routes but I have not been able to process both responses:

```
  const array1 = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    },
    id: id,
  };

    const array2 = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
      },
      todo: "ToDo",
  };

  const req1 = axios.post(`${url}/user`, array1);
  const req2 = axios.post(`${url}/todos`, array2);

  try {
    const {data1, data2} = await axios.all([req1, req2]);
    console.log("concatenated data: " + data1 + data2);
    return res.json(data1 + data2);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

The response I get by console is:

```
concatenated data: undefinedundefined
```

And the answer I have for insomnia is:

```
null
```

I appreciate suggestions about it. Thanks!

Comment: Replace braces with brackets: `const [data1, data2] = await axios.all([req1, req2]);` because `axios.all` (like `Promise.all`) resolves to an _array_.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I received the answer but it arrived as an object  ```  [object Object][object Object] ```and it was not possible to treat it with stringify because it generated a error ```  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON ```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that I could not use the `axios.all()` method and do the requests in sequence with `axios.post()` methods. That way I was able to receive and treat the responses as expected.

```
const array1 = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  id: id
};

const array2 = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  todos: todo
};

try {
  const { data: data1 } = await axios.post(`${url}/user`, array1);
  const { data: data2 } = await axios.post(`${url}/todos`, array2);

  users.push(data1, data2);

  return res.json(users);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

However, I would appreciate suggestions to implement the use of `axios.all()` or another way to perform concurrent requests in a more optimized way, in this example.